# Is it possible to debug a app that was signed and installed as a release build?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I have an Android apk that was generated and signed trough the archival process in Visual Studio (if you right click on the .Android project and select "Archive").

When I install the app and then try to debug, it seems that this signed version is uninstalled and then redeployed before the debug starts.

However when I deploy a release build by selecting the Release configuration, and then select Debug config, it does start debugging without uninstalling or clearing the app data.

Is there a way to to the same with an signed/archived build, or has this something to do with the signing that prevents it from doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release versions are usually optimizated versions and all Debug symbols and references are removed during compilation time.
Even "row numbers" are lost, so it's not possible for a Debugger to let Source and Runtime in sync without any debugging information.

So finally answer is No.

Comment: thanks.
I was trying to investigate an issue where the signed app does not resume, but i will create a separate question for that.